# How can I parse this GTFS string in Swift 4+

Tags: swift, csv

This is an imported partial GTFS string in CSV format:

```
   83,51001,"Ballston Metro G, Fairfax Dr, EB @ N Stafford, NS",38.882092,-77.110876,"http://www.arlingtontransit.com/pages/rider-tools/realtime/?Stop=A51001#realTimeResultsContainer"
```

Please note the commas in the address. What are good ways to avoid splitting the string at these points, ie, not to split between quotes?

I've been using this code so far:

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL as URL)
                    let content = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    let parsedCSV = content!.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

Comma seperation is what I need except for the quoted string.

Many thanks

Comment: There are a few good CSV parsing libraries for Swift. Best to use one. Parsing general CSV properly is far more complicated than most people realize.

Comment: Crap. typo. I've edited the question

Comment: @rmaddy I looked at github for just that. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=csvparser&type=Repositories

Answer (score 1):

A *simple* example of using regular expression.

```
let csvText = """
83,51001,"Ballston Metro G, Fairfax Dr, EB @ N Stafford, NS",38.882092,-77.110876,"http://www.arlingtontransit.com/pages/rider-tools/realtime/?Stop=A51001#realTimeResultsContainer"
"""

let pattern = "(?:\"((?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\"|([^,\"\\n]*))[ \t]*(,|$)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)

var parsedCSV: [String] = []
regex.enumerateMatches(in: csvText, options: .anchored, range: NSRange(0..<csvText.utf16.count)) {match, flags, stop in
    guard let match = match else {fatalError()}
    if match.range(at: 1).location != NSNotFound {
        //matching double-quoted item
        let field = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: csvText)!].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"\"", with: "\"")
        parsedCSV.append(field)
    } else if match.range(at: 2).location != NSNotFound {
        let field = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: csvText)!].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        parsedCSV.append(field)
    }
    let separator = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 3), in: csvText)!]
    switch separator {
    case "": //end of line
        stop.pointee = true
    default: //comma
        break
    }
}
print(parsedCSV) //->["83", "51001", "Ballston Metro G, Fairfax Dr, EB @ N Stafford, NS", "38.882092", "-77.110876", "http://www.arlingtontransit.com/pages/rider-tools/realtime/?Stop=A51001#realTimeResultsContainer"]
```

Some CSV can contain control characters, I hope your GTFS would not be so complex.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up up using an NSScanner. It's fast!

```
for i in 1..<objectArray.count - 1 {
                        autoreleasepool(invoking: { () -> () in
                            let item: [String] = objectArray[i]

                            for j in 0..<item.count {
                                let tempString = item[j]
                                let scanner = Scanner(string: tempString)

                                var bitBucket: NSString!  
                                var stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_lon: NSString?

                                scanner.scanUpTo(",", into: &stop_id)

                                scanner.scanLocation = scanner.scanLocation + 1
                                scanner.scanUpTo(",", into: &stop_code)

                                scanner.scanLocation = scanner.scanLocation + 2
                                scanner.scanUpTo("\"", into: &stop_name)

                                scanner.scanLocation = scanner.scanLocation + 2
                                scanner.scanUpTo(",", into: &stop_lat)

                                scanner.scanLocation = scanner.scanLocation + 1
                                scanner.scanUpTo(",", into: &stop_lon)

                                scanner.scanUpTo("\n", into: &bitBucket)

                                let newResource = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: busStopEntity, into: context)
                                newResource.setValue(stop_id, forKey: "stop_id")
                                newResource.setValue(stop_name, forKey: "stop_name")
                                newResource.setValue(stop_code, forKey: "stop_code")

                                let tempString1 = String(stop_lat!)
                                let myFloat1 = (tempString1 as NSString).doubleValue
                                newResource.setValue(myFloat1, forKey: "stop_lat")

                                let tempString2 = String(stop_lon!)
                                let myFloat2 = (tempString2 as NSString).doubleValue
                                newResource.setValue(myFloat2, forKey: "stop_lon")                             
                                newResource.setValue(date, forKey: "update_date")
                            }

                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            } catch let error as NSError  {
                                print("Error While Saving Data: \(error.userInfo)")
                            }
                        }
```